# Arcmap: a different delimiter when symbolizing "Unique values, many"?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, symbology, fields-attributes

In Arcmap 10.1, is it possible to use something other than a comma to separate the value fields when symbolizing by "Unique values, many"?

Answer (score 1):

I am looking at 10.2, but check your 10.1 menus to see if this option is there. Click on the "Advanced" button in the bottom right of the Symbology tab menu. Then select "Field Delimiter..." and enter the new symbol that you would like to use instead of the comma. As a warning, you will need to add values again after setting this, so don't spend the time to set up symbols beforehand.

Comment: You're welcome - glad it worked!